# Десериализация json

Tags: c#, json

Здравствуйте!
Мне нужно обратится  к серверу, получить от него ответ и десериализовать его.
Когда я захожу по адресу сервера, получаю следующее: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. данные обернуты в тег string и отсутствуют кавычки и квадратные скобки, характерные для json. Когда я просто читаю поток ответа, то получаю просто "Female:Died;Female:Died;Female:Died". При попытке десериализации вылетает исключение:
Необработанное исключение "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" в System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Ожидается состояние "Element".. Обнаружен "Text" с именем "", пространство имен "".

Я связываю это с неверным для json форматом данных, но как еще это можно десериализовать?
Код:

```
{     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://server....");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer Interpretation = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<StatisticEvent>));
        List<StatisticEvent> statistic = (List<StatisticEvent>)Interpretation.ReadObject(stream);}


  public class StatisticEvent
    {
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собака была зарыта в том, что это вовсе не json и десериализовать его бессмысленно. Лучший вариант в таком случае получить разграниченные данные по этому поводу- streamreader считать поток до конца и использовать Split() для удаления из полученной строки символов ";" ":" " ". При этом каждая строка между этими символами будет лежать в своей ячейке массива